# Recursive timeout loses visibility to itself

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have defined an `API` object:

```
function API() {
  var self = this;
  return {
    getRandomArticle: function() {
      $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=50000&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
        for(var id in data.query.pages) {
          console.log(data.query.pages[id].extract);
        }
      });
    },
    repeatAPICall: function() {
      self.getRandomArticle();
      console.log(self);
      setTimeout(self.repeatAPICall, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

And then I instantiated the API object with `window.test = new API();`.
When I head over to Chrome Dev tools and call `window.test.repeatAPICall()`, it works once, then it fails and says `TypeError: Object #<API> has no method 'getRandomArticle'`

I suspect that somehow the recursive call is behaving differently than I intended, what am I doing wrong?

**Working code:**

```
function API() {
  var self = this;
    self.getRandomArticle = function() {
      $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exchars=50000&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
        for(var id in data.query.pages) {
          console.log(data.query.pages[id].extract);
        }
      });
    },
    self.repeatAPICall = function() {
      self.getRandomArticle();
      console.log(self);
      setTimeout(self.repeatAPICall, 5000);
    }
    return this;
}
window.test = new API();
```

Comment: Add the methods to the `prototype`, were `this` is the instance.

Comment: Try using your variable "self" instead of using "this" in your functions. "this" has interesting semantics in JS.

Comment: You're defining `self` but not using it... The whole purpose of `self`  is to avoid problems like this. (And, as a side note, it should be `var self`, otherwise you're using the same global variable for all instances.)

Comment: @Juhana Oh yes, I messed that up in my post. Error/post updated.

Comment: @elclanrs Wouldn't adding them to the `prototype` only reduce the memory footprint? I don't understand how it will make the recursive call work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you've fixed "self" vs. "this" the next change is to use

```
self.getRandomArticle= ...
self.repeatAPICall=...
```

and then just return self/this.  That should work.  Right now, you have two objects - this and the one you return.

Comment: I finally understood it when you mentioned me having 2 objects! Thanks, updating my code for future Googlers. One more question by the way, when would you actually use `return {funcName: function(){});`? I feel like I've seen it quite a bit.

Comment: When you are creating an object on the fly without a constructor or prototype support.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the passing of `this.repeatAPICall` into `setTimeout`. When you call a method in JavaScript, the `this` keyword points to the object that called it:

```
var something = {
    foo : function(){
        return this;
    }
};

something.foo();    //=> something
```

However, if you assign the function to a different variable, the context changes (to the global `window` object):

```
var something = {
    foo : function(){
        return this;
    }
};

something.foo();    //=> something
var bar = something.foo;
bar();              //=> window
```

This is what's happening above; you're passing a reference to the function to `setTimeout`, which is then losing the correct context.

Instead, you need to pass in a function which keeps the context; you could use the `self = this` statement like so:

```
repeatAPICall: function() {
  self = this;
  self.getRandomArticle();
  setTimeout(function(){
    self.repeatAPICall();
    }, 5000);
```

This creates anonymous function which remembers the state of the `self` object (this is how JavaScript variable scope works). When that function gets called, it can then call `repeatAPICall` as a method on that object, rather than as a function with no context.

The accepted answer avoids having to do this (each method can access `self`), but hopefully this explains why it wasn't working.